# Busybox OOM killer

Tags: linux, memory, out-of-memory, virtual-machine, busybox

I'm testing and embedded linux CPE with Busybox;

```
BusyBox v1.00 (2012.07.10-03:48+0000) multi-call binary
```

I want to try consuming all virtual memory available on the box to test the behavior of the OOM killer.

Here the memory stats:

```
# free
          total         used         free       shared      buffers
Mem:        27876        21824         6052            0          708
Swap:            0            0            0
Total:        27876        21824         6052
#
```

The problem is that the tools on the CPE is very limited, so commands like "vi", "dd" dont exist.

I found an article on the web:
http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2006/11/30/linux-out-of-memory.html

But haveing problems executing the scripts, because of the lack of build in tools on the device.

Any ideas how I can consume all available memory on command line?

Comment: Wouldn't unix.stackexchange.com be better place for this question?

Comment: Yeah, I surpose you are right about that.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it under busybox but i [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) may do the trick (I belive `:(){ :|: & };:`) should work on any ksh). It will spawn processes recursively so it will consume all of resources at some point (unless you run out of, say, pids faster - but I would think that on embedded devices memory is primary concern).

Comment: Thank you for the reply - fork bomb doesnt seem to work though. 
# :(){ :|: & };:)  
syntax error  
#

Comment: Try without `#`. It just denotes prompt.

Comment: Hi, it was actually written without the # - sadly :(

Comment: Hmm. You added additional `)` (it was part of surrounding text). Try `:(){ :|: & };:`.